# What are shell command to get current date and date 3 hrs back?

Tags: shell, command, sh

To get the current command we simple shell script command

date

if you want to get a custom date format

```
NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T")
```

Am not getting simple command to get the 3hrs back date with above format , any one can help me please .

i used below shell command with perl like below , but i do not want another additional dependency perl , i just need to shell command

```
CURRENT_DATE=`perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime);$d = strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(time());print $d'`
CURRENT_DATE_MINUS_3_HRS_DATE=`perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime);$d = strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(time() - 10800);print $d'`
```

Comment: Try something like : a=$(($(date +"%s")-10800));echo "Now is $(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T") and before it was $(date -d @$a  +"%Y-%m-%d %T")"

Answer (score 1):

The `date` command has the nice keyword `ago` for the date you can give with `-d` option:

```
date -d '3 hours ago' +"%Y-%m-%d %T"
```

Comment: Nice ! Thanks didn't know that one....would you happen to have a link with those "nice keywords" ? :) ... man is definitively not complete :D

Comment: does  this worked on mac ? not working giving below 
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]

Comment: @AndreGelinas, for complete documentation, look at `info date`, or the manual is online: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html -- you want to read "Examples of date" and "Date input formats" for all the gory details.

Comment: The natural language descriptions are GNU extensions (and not terribly well documented). See my answer for a solution using BSD `date`.

Answer (score 1):

Shows the current date:

`date "+%Y-%m-%d %T"`

Show date back to 3 hours:

`date -d "-3 Hours" "+%Y-%m-%d %T"`

Some of the other things you can try:

```
# Back to 3 days
date -d "-3 Days" "+%Y-%m-%d %T"

# Next to 3 days
date -d "3 Days" "+%Y-%m-%d %T"

# Back to 2 Years and 3 Hours
date -d "-2 Years -3 Hours" "+%Y-%m-%d %T"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the BSD `date` that ships with macOS, use the `-v` option.

```
$ date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"
2018-11-08 16:25:21
$ date -v -3H +"%Y-%m-%d %T"
2018-11-08 13:25:26
```